# Is it possible to add filters to all columns in a pivot table?

Tags: excel

I was wondering if it is possible to add filters to a pivot table like it is to add filters to a normal table (by pressing ctrl+shift+l). I tried looking this up online but could not find any credible information. I have created a pivot table and I need to filter the data columns.

Thanks,

G

Comment: Drag the column in to the "Report Filter" and filter it. OR right click on the column and "Add to report filter". OR you can just hit the drop down next to the column in the field list and pick the value(s) you want to filter by. At any rate this should probably be asked on superuser.com since this isn't a programming (or formula) related question, but rather functionality of a pretty common piece of software and its UI.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the drop down below each column heading in the pivot table. It works as a normal filter.